# Getting Not all code paths returns a value when i gave return type as boolean

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

`enter code here`    public bool GetComprehendMedicalModel(string claimId)
    {
        try
        {
            var userId = _ClaimData.GetUserIdFromCalim(claimId);
           _PDFProcess.MedicalModel(claimId, userId, false, _logger);
           _PDFProcess.ConditionAlerts(claimId);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

```
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question

Comment: What is supposed to happen if an exception occurs? You don't have a return value there.

Comment: You are missing a return value inside the catch block. The compiler see this as a possible path that your code could take and complains that there is no return value if the catch is taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a value in `GetComprehendMedicalModel` method.

return `false` in catch

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}
```

or after catch return `true` or `false` according to your senario.

```cs
public bool GetComprehendMedicalModel(string claimId)
{
    try
    {
        var userId = _ClaimData.GetUserIdFromCalim(claimId);
       _PDFProcess.MedicalModel(claimId, userId, false, _logger);
       _PDFProcess.ConditionAlerts(claimId);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```